# Doing a complex join on files

Tags: unix, join

I have files (~1k) that look (basically) like this:

```
NAME1.txt
NAME    ATTR    VALUE
NAME1   x       1      
NAME1   y       2
...

NAME2.txt
NAME    ATTR    VALUE
NAME2   x       19
NAME2   y       23
...
```

Where the ATTR collumn is same in everyfile and the name column is just some version of the filename. I would like to combine them together into 1 file that looks like:

```
All_data.txt
ATTR    NAME1_VALUE    NAME2_VALUE    NAME3_VALUE ...
X       1              19             ...
y       2              23             ...
...
```

Is there simple way to do this with just command line utilities or will I have to resort to writing some script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a script.
gawk is the obvious candidate 
You could create an associative array in a BEGIN block, using FILENAME as the KEY and
ATTR " " VALUE 
values as the value. 
Then create your output in an END block. 
gawk can process all txt files together by using *txt as the filename

It's a bit optimistic to expect there to be a ready made command to do exactly what you want.
Very few command join data horizontally.

Comment: I ended up writing some perl script to take care of it.